# How to install aircrack on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: software-installation, make, configure

I have downloaded the tar.gz package from the site and then I have extracted using `tar -zxvf` command as mentioned over there. After that I used `sudo apt-get install build-essential` then I further installed `libssl-dev`. Then I changed directory to the aircrack folder. But when I type either `sudo make` or just `make` I am getting this same error. I don't know what to do. I have installed the file what they have asked in the error as well. Still the same error is shown. Okay I am not permitted to upload images.

The error is :

```
common.mak:85: *** Cannot find development files for any supported version of libnl. install either libnl1 or libnl3..  Stop.
```

Answer (score 4):

**How to install without compiling**
Execute this command in your Terminal:

> sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng

Comment: +1 There might be a spelling mistake in your command, though.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to install it from source (though Naveens's answer would be easier) you must install libnl-dev.

To install from source you need to install the -dev packages for every library that the program you are compiling uses. Whenever a program you are compiling asks for a library look it up in synaptic (if you don't have it run `apt-get install synaptic` as root) then select the library's -dev package, which contains the headers that the program needs to compile to the library.